# how to collect items of a set which are the multiplication of another set

Tags: kotlin, set

I have stuck this problem: "Your function receives two sets of Int. Return a new set of elements in the first set that are multiples of the size of the second set."
It is from Hyperskill, and the code I created is not accepted although it correctly ran in IntelliJ. What can be the problem?

```
fun solution(first: Set<Int>, second: Set<Int>): Set<Int> {
    val tempSet = mutableSetOf<Int>()
    var finalSet = emptySet<Int>()
    var isDiv = false
    for (f in first) {
        for (s in second) {
            if(f % s == 0){
                isDiv = true
                if(s == second.last()){
                    tempSet.add(f)
                }
            } else { break }
        }
        isDiv = false
    }
    finalSet = tempSet
    return finalSet
}
```

Comment: "elements in the first set that are multiples of the size of the second set." I don't see you checking the _size_ of the second set.

Comment: Also: "the code I created is not accepted" - what do you mean by "not accepted"? It failed to compile? It gave the wrong results? It ran too slowly? Please be more precise in your questions.

Comment: Hyperskill has its own IDE where you can put your code and can check if it is ok. It gives a feedback of "Failed test #2 of 3. Wrong answer". But when I copy the code to my IDE, it  seems to work fine.

Comment: The question asks for multiples of the size of the second set, not multiples of elements from the second set. Your code looks at elements of the second set and not the size. Also, what's the point of your `finalSet` variable?

Comment: It says "Wrong answer" but when you test it locally "it seems to work fine". That sounds as if you had misunderstood the requirements.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I misunderstood the question. I reconsidered it and Joffrey was right. Thanks again.

Comment: This is a good exercise that reminds you that when you are given a task, you need to pay proper attention to the wording. This is important in interview situations and at work. This exercise caught you out because you assumed the elements of the second set were important, but in fact you only need to know its size (so in a workplace situation, you might ask why don't we just pass an integer to the function instead).

Answer (score 0):

Going off of what the wording is, Values from the first set that are multiples of the *Size* of the second set it could be done like this?

Note: None of this has been tested***

```
fun solution(first: Set<Int>, secondSize: Int): Set<Int> {
    val mResult = mutableSetOf<Int>()
    // Loop through first set, checking if they are 
    // multiples of second sets Size
    first.forEach { value ->
        if (value % secondSize == 0) {
            mResult.add(value)
        }
    }
    
    // Return the resulting set
    return mResult
}
```

Or, if you need to see if a value at each index is a multiple of any value within the second set like you're code is currently you can do it this way

```
fun solution(first: Set<Int>, second: Set<Int>): Set<Int> {
    val mResult = mutableSetOf<Int>()
    // Loop through first set
    first.forEach { value ->
        // Loop through second, checking each value against the value from first, 
        // also check if resulting set already contains said value so we don't 
        // end up with multiples of the same value
        second.ForEach {
            If (value % it == 0 && !mResult.contains(it)) {
                mResult.add(value)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Return the resulting set
    return mResult
}
```

I typed this up on a phone so double check for typos. In case you're unfamiliar and for anyone else who may not know, kotlin has some nifty things you can take advantage of. I prefer to use .forEach when possible, it saves some typing and is way easier to read when you're looking back through code. If you ever need to know the index of the loop, you can use .forEachIndexed but this isn't available for everything. And you'll need to specify the name for the index and value like this:

```
mSomeList.forEachIndexed { index, value ->
    // Do something with index and value
}
```

Using mResult.contains(it) returns true if the list contains that value, seems clear enough. But adding a ! At the begining will basically make it return the opposite. This is the same concept as == and !=.